# Child object rotation relative to parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've been trying to rotate my player's gun target along with the player. My player keeps shooting to right side even though he's facing left.
I've created a target called Firepoint, it's set to as a child Object of the player. I want it to change as the character changes it's direction. 
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Here's the code of the player.

```
 public void Move()
{
    float controlThrow = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
    Vector2 playerVelocity = new Vector2(controlThrow * runSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
    myRigidBody.velocity = playerVelocity;

    bool playerHasHorizontalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidBody.velocity.x) > Mathf.Epsilon; 

    myAnimator.SetBool("Walking", playerHasHorizontalSpeed);
}

 public void Flipsprite()
{

    bool playerhashorizontalspeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidBody.velocity.x) > Mathf.Epsilon;

    if (playerhashorizontalspeed)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(myRigidBody.velocity.x), 1f);
        transform.rotation = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(firePoint.transform.localScale.x), 1f);

    }


}
```

Comment: `transform.rotation` is of type `Quaternion` not `Vector2` ...

Comment: why using `> Mathf.Epsilon` and not `> 0` ? `Mathf.Epsilon` is "the smallest value different from 0"

Comment: the main problem is that the scale has no influence on the rotation .. and I guess you are using something like `firePoint.transform.forward` or `firepoint.transform.right` to determin the direction right?

Comment: @derHugo I'm Instantiating the direction from firepoint.position.  

Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation)

Comment: could you add the relevant code for shooting then?

Comment: @derHugo
Here's the shooting code. 

FireContinuously()
    {

        while (true)
        { 
        GameObject laser = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as GameObject;
        laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(projectileSpeed, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(projectileFiringPeriod);
        }

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the rotation is not effected by scaling. Only the relative scales and positions.

Also why are you using `> Mathf.Epsilon` and not simply `> 0`. As far as I understand you only need to check if it is not 0 ... using `Mathf.Epsilon` is such a small difference that it actually doesn't matter.

```
public void Move()
{
    float controlThrow = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
    Vector2 playerVelocity = new Vector2(controlThrow * runSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
    myRigidBody.velocity = playerVelocity;

    bool playerHasHorizontalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidBody.velocity.x) > 0; 

    myAnimator.SetBool("Walking", playerHasHorizontalSpeed);
}

// store the last direction
int direction;

public void Flipsprite()
{
    bool playerhashorizontalspeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidBody.velocity.x) > 0;

    if (playerhashorizontalspeed)
    {
        // update the direction
        direction = Mathf.Sign(myRigidBody.velocity.x);
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(direction, 1f);
    }
}
```

Then when you are shooting multiply the direction also with `direction`

```
private IEnumerator FireContinuously() 
{ 
    while (true) 
    { 
        GameObject laser = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation); 
        laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(projectileSpeed * direction, 0); 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(projectileFiringPeriod); 
    } 
}
```

---

a small hint:

If you make the type of

```
public RigidBody2D bullet
```

and drag in the according prefab again than you don't need to use `GetComponent` but could directly use

```
var laser = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
laser.velocity = ...
```

Comment: I was supposed to change the value to zero but forgot in the end since I was too deep in trying to solve this. 

The code works for a while and changes the direction to right when he's facing left...

Comment: yep I updated ... you should actually store the direction ... problem is that Sign returns positive for 0 movement as well so if you are not using and shooting it flips to right as well. Now it should do it

Comment: I've got a similar enough question to not warrant an new thread. How would I go about taking into account a parent objects potentially negative scale when calculating a new rotation? EG: Quaternion newRot = transform.localRotation + offsetRot; My current workaround is to just *-1 the parent's localScale, calculate the rotation, then *-1 the parent's localScale again.